# Is it possible to use string interpolation with the pipe operator?

Tags: elixir

When, for example, you are mutating a string through several pipe steps and want to add it as a string variable interpolation.

```
"Hello-World" 
|> String.downcase 
|> String.slice(0..4) 
|> String.to_atom("var_#{&1}")
```

Instead of:

```
str = 
  "Hello-World" 
  |> String.downcase 
  |> String.slice(0..4) 
String.to_atom("var_#{str}")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can create an anonymous function and pipe into that:

```
iex(1)> "Hello-World" |> String.downcase |> String.slice(0..4)
        |> (&String.to_atom("var_#{&1}")).()
:var_hello
```